# How to understand pandas Period object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Period object from this:

```
temp = pd.Period('2001Q3', freq='Q-DEC')
```

From the the book(Python for Data Analysis), `Q-DEC` means

> Quarterly dates anchored on last calendar day of each
>   month, for year ending in indicated month (JAN, FEB,
>   MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, or DEC)

What this exact mean?

From my common sense, `2001Q3` includes August, September, and October. So how to deal with December(`Q-DEC`) here?

And can anyone explain the `temp` variable concisely? Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question before and this directly from documentation explains Q-Dec perfectly

> “Period conversions with anchored frequencies are particularly useful
>   for working with various quarterly data common to economics, business,
>   and other fields. Many organizations define quarters relative to the
>   month in which their fiscal year starts and ends. Thus, first quarter
>   of 2011 could start in 2010 or a few months into 2011. Via anchored
>   frequencies, pandas works for all quarterly frequencies Q-JAN through
>   Q-DEC.”

Not all organization will have their Q3 ends in October.

And temp is just a temporary variable saying Q3 ends at Dec